# Restarting BLE Scan after bluetooth restart (ANDROID)

Tags: android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have written an android service that continuously scans for a specific device and when the device is found it connects with the device, reads data and disconnects. When the device is advertising again, the service does the same again.
In general, it is working fine and showing expected behavior but if I turn off the bluetooth and switch it on again, the service doesn't connect to the advertising device. I have tried scanning again as soon as bluetooth is switched on. I have also tried to reconnect to GATT but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. It might be useful for others facing the same issue. My issue was that I had a check in place in my Scan method to ensure that scan starts only if my BluetoothGatt object is null.

```
    public void startNordicScan() {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "startScan");
            BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
        scanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }
```

So if I start scan again without making `mGatt`(BluetoothGatt) object, devices will not be discovered.